# Cannot redeclare class Mysqli

Tags: php

Hi I just finished reading a beginner book on PHP and I wana start to create my own login.I did not get very far and I got an error that I can;t seem to fix.

I have 3 files

```
    index.php

    session_start();
    require 'DB_ACCES/connect.php';

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $conn = new Mysqli();
    }

    constants.php

    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    define('DB_USER' , 'root');
    define('DB_PWD' , '');

    connect.php

    require '../includes/constants.php';

    class Mysqli{

        private $conn;

        function __construct() {
            $this->conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST , DB_USER , DB_PWD) or die(mysqli_error());
        }
    }
```

When I run index.php I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Mysqli in D:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\MyWork\Blog\DB_ACCES\connect.php on line 4
```

What am I doing wrong here and how can I repair it?

Comment: Whats the problem with the error message? ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bug is exactly what the error states.

Mysqli is an existing class that's part of a very common php shared library `mysqli`.  You can't redeclare it.

Change your classname to `MyMysqli` or something.

```
class MyMysqli{

    private $conn;

    function __construct() {
        $this->conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST , DB_USER , DB_PWD) or die(mysqli_error());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Mysqli already exists in php, since php is case insensitive the word mysqli it self is reserved and can't be used in any spelling what so ever.

you will be able to create your own class which extends mysqli, so it'll basically inherit all attributes and methods of the existing mysqli class

```
class MyMySQLi extends MySQLi 
{
    private $conn;

    function __construct() {
        $this->conn = parent::__construct(DB_HOST , DB_USER , DB_PWD) or die(mysqli_error());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP environment includes mysqli which is a module that makes available a class named mysqli. Just name your class something else.